# How to enable Boost Geometry Extension Dissolve support with boost 1.58?

Tags: boost-geometry

I'm new to boost::geometry. I'm using boost 1.58 in my project and I would like to enable extension algorithm "dissolve" in my application. But I can't find the related patch with 1.58. May I just pull the developer branch source code from the link below?

https://github.com/boostorg/geometry/tree/develop/include/boost/geometry/extensions/algorithms

Best Regards,

Alex

Answer (score 1):

Copying from current development branch will not work. The dissolve algorithm from development branch is too much changed from the 1.58 version. It will not compile.

You could try to get the dissolve version from 1.58 using git, it is tagged with the tag "boost-1.58.0". That dissolve version might do what you want (but it is not in released, and problems have been fixed later, so maybe it might not).

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try.